# Custom Drupal theme template files not being used

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-theming, drupal-themes

I am trying to organize my theme folder, which has node theming overrides for dozens of views.  Basically I have two different styles and I want them all to look the same, more or less.

Is there a way in template.php that I can do this? And what is the best way?

I tried this code in my theme's hook_preprocess_node function:

```
switch($vars['view']->name) {
 case 'taxonomy_term' :
   switch($vars['view']->current_display) {
     case 'page' :
       array_push($vars['template_files'], 'list-view');
     default :
       break;
   }
   break;
 default :
   break;
}
```

And when I look in theme developer, I can see the list-view.tpl.php file there, but its not actually *using* that file from my theme directory. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in [theme()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme/6) Drupal will only actually use a template if it exists according to [drupal_discover_template()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/drupal_discover_template/6).

You should try to figure out if that is the case.

- place some debug code in the theme() function in *includes/theme.inc* to see what `drupal_discover_template()` returns for vairious template calls.

Can it find it? 
If not:

- place some debug code in `drupal_discover_template()` to find out where Drupal thinks it no longer is a template.

My gut-feeling says that it is due to subdirectories where the template files reside, but which you have not added to the `template_files` variable: **views/lists/some_list.tpl.php** is not the same as **some_list.tpl.php**.

Comment: Good idea — I got that code to work by just using other template files which already registered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebuild the cache for the tpl.php file to be picked up.

Comment: Even when clear the cache using devel/drush/performance it doesn't work. Nor did trying to register my default template using a hook_theme function.

Comment: I think you need to rescan templates in the views theming information for the view to pick up the templates.

Comment: Also I don't think you need that piece of code. Hope this helps http://drupal.org/node/352970

Comment: I already know how to name the templates — e.g. node-view-view_name-page.tpl.php, node-view-view_name-page-1.tpl.php — I'm looking for a way to re-use the same template for multiple views so I don't have to create all of those files.